# Ferry schedules on Lago di Como

Tags: italy, short-connections, ferries

I'll be visiting Lago di Como in May, and want to make a "round trip" from Como north to Bellagio and then back south to Lecco. The [published schedule](https://www.navigazionelaghi.it/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/01P2024_Web_Como.pdf) shows the earliest  ferry from Como I can get arriving in Bellagio at 11:50, and the one from Bellagio to Lecco departing at 12:00, with the next one only going at 15:00.

Would it be realistic to change from one to the other? For me, this determines whether I will spend the following night in Lecco or can reach a train to travel on.

Comment: I would not bet on it. If it is an alternative, there are also buses from Bellagio to Lecco if you miss the 12:00 ferry and want to get earlier to Lecco than you can with the 15:00 ferry.

Answer (score 2):

10 minutes is a tight connection but it's worth the risk, considering that train is not the only option to travel from Lecco to Como: there is also a bus service (line C40). Last departure from Lecco at 21.10 and it arrives in Como at 22.10 [(timetable)](https://www.asfautolinee.it/orari_pdf/invernale/C40.pdf). The final destination (Stazione autolinee) is a few hundred meters from the piers.

Comment: I think this travel is about a ferry, the train is for after the ferry tour.

Comment: if the train is too early if taking the later ferry (at 15), and the bus is a better option for the return trip, this may be a crucial factor on the planning.

Comment: The misunderstanding is that I'm traveling on from Lecco towards Bergamo, and the line is interrupted there due to construction work.